# Specific adjective to qualify a religion

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, religion

I am looking for a word to describe a religion which is flexible or liberal enough to accept a variety of folk beliefs, magical practices, other demons etc. 
The author (translator) of the text which I am editing used “absorbent religion” (the text was translated from Polish), but I am quite sure there is a much better word, which seems almost on the tip of my tongue, nevertheless I am unable to conjure it up. Some help would be much appreciated.
PS.This is an academic paper about an ancient religion.

Answer (score 1):

If the adaptation represents a substantial, rather than formal or stylistic change, then the word you are looking for is [*synchretic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncretism?wprov=sfti1).

If the adaptation is merely a change of form dictated by the language and culture of a particular group, but the belief system is not changed in any fundamental way, then one could speak of *acculturation*.

Your author, however, may have intentionally avoided this terminology and opted for something more neutral, which you could translate as, say, *flexible*.